# Are there any more immediate destructors available than Finalize?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I created a wrapper class around mysql connector for .net to make it more comfortable to use (and to swap for something else which I'm planning down the road).

The idea was that upon every request, I spawn a new instance of the wrapper, do whatever and when the request is responded, the wrapper object should be destroyed and the connection closed in its finalize sub.

I did some load testing though and it would appear that I run out of pooled connections if pushed hard enough since the wrapper objects aren't being destroyed fast enough.

So.. is there any other sub I can override, maybe something that would execute immediately after all the interactions with said object are completed?

Comment: Show the code in question. It would help...

Comment: Right now this question is very vague. Even with a selected answer this question has little value to the community. You should post your code to make it more useful to others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the class implements `IDisposable` you can wrap its usage in a `using` block which would dispose of it as soon as the block exits. You should do this for all classes that implement `IDisposable` to ensure their resources are cleaned up in a timely manner, otherwise you are at the mercy of the garbage collector.

For example:

```
Using myObject As New MyWrapperType(wrappedThing) 
    ' Do stuff with myObject
End Using
```

And in C#

```
using(var myObject = new MyWrapper(wrappedThing))
{
    // Do stuff with myObject
}
```

When the `using` block goes out of scope `myObject` will be disposed of.

For more information: [Using Statement (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

**UPDATE**

I should add that if you are adding `IDisposable` to your wrapper then you should call dispose on the object(s) that you are wrapping so they they also get disposed when the `Using` block exits.